# PHP regex to accept Japanese and english languages with no special character

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am trying to create a regex to filter only alphabets or numbers from English and Japanese languages. This is what I have tried,

```
preg_match('/[\p{L}\p{N}\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Han}]+/u', $value)
```

But I am not getting the desired result. What might I be doing wrong?
this one also i tried

```
preg_match('/[\p{Cn}\p{N}]+/u', $value)
```

also, I need to prevent special characters

```
('/[(a-zA-Z 0-9\_\{\}\!\$\%\&\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\-\~)(\p{Cn})]/', $value))
```

this one wont work together

Comment: Try `/^(?:(?=[\p{L}\p{N}])[\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Han}A-Za-z])+$/u`

Comment: Can you provide sample strings with the desired output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this regex : it will match letters (upper and lower case), numbers and unicode characters from `katakana`, `hiragana` and `han` subset

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Han} $]+/u', $value)
```

**Edit** : added `space` to the list of allowed chars and `$` and `^` to match entiere string.

- `STORE-11 ぼ <>?>>^^ † ‡ dd NN` will return 0 (no match)
- `ぼ abc 12` will return 1 (matched)

demo of the regex with given examples : https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/oef

Comment: two cases are there for my current situation
case 1: add all languages and numbers without any special character

or
case 2: add Japanese language ,numbers and English without any special chars

any one of this is ok for my current req

Comment: @manu does the provided regex work for your use case ? if no, can you provide some strings that have to work and some that have to fail ?

Comment: case: 1 STORE-11 ぼ <>?>>^^ † ‡ dd NN  -------need to throw error
case 2:  ぼ abc 12 -------need to work